# NSNotification addObserver selector could not open a NSBeginAlertSheet sheet on window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter, alerts

I have two different window Controllers. First is a custom panel window controller and another is main window controller. In panel window there is a panel window and there are button on that panel. On click of those buttons I am posting notification like :

```
In PanelWindowController:
    -(IBAction)okAndCancelButtonClicked:(id)sender
    {
        [self postNotification:sender];
    }

    -(void)postNotification:(id)sender
    {
        if([sender tag]!=2){
            [[self window]  endSheet:self.panel returnCode:NSModalResponseCancel];
            [self.panel orderOut:self];
        }
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[sender tag]],@"value",nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PanelButtonClickedNotification" object:self userInfo:dict];
    }
```

Now, in my main window controller, I am trying to open a `NSBeginAlertSheet` in the `selector` of `addObserver` of `NSNotificationCenter`. Following is the `addObserver` `selector` declaration in `init` method of my main window controller:

```
MainWindowController

-(id) init{
..// some code here
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(okButtonClicked:) name:@"PanelButtonClickedNotification" object:[self panelClass]];
return self;
}
```

the implementation of `okButtonClicked` is the following :

```
- (void) okButtonClicked:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    if ([[notification object] isEqualTo:[self panelClass]])
    {
        if([[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"value"] integerValue] == 1)
        {
            // Yes Button in the Panel is clicked
        }
        else if([[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"value"] integerValue] == 0)
        {
            // No Button in the Panel is clicked
            NSBeginAlertSheet(@"Alert", @"Ok", nil, nil, [[self view] window], self,nil, nil,nil,@"Alert is being shown on window.");
        }

    }
}
```

When user clicks No button on Panel, an alert on the window should be displayed. But the alert is never shown. I also tried `[NSApp keyWindow]` and `[NSApp mainWindow]` instead of `[[self view] window]`. 
And, If I run the alert independently of window, it is displayed:

```
NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
 [alert setMessageText:@"Alert"];
 [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
 NSImage *icon=[NSImage imageNamed:@"warning.png"];
 [alert setIcon:icon];
 [alert runModal];
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything here.

The alert is not displayed in any of the methods called after the notification is received.
PFA my sample project : https://www.dropbox.com/s/0xfe4bk17v9girj/PanelApplication.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with the notifications, it was the panel which was causing problems:
I was opening the panel in my main window controller:

`[[self window] beginSheet:self.panelClass.panel completionHandler:nil];`

And the closing action of the panel was written in the Panel window controller. Because of this reason no `NSBeginAlertSheet` was not being shown once the custom panel was loaded/ unloaded on the main window.

Therefore moving the following piece of code from panel window controller to main window controller solved the problem:

`[[self window]  endSheet:self.panelClass.panel returnCode:NSModalResponseCancel];
[self.panelClass.panel orderOut:self];`

Answer (score 0):

It is a little difficult to tell, but my best guess would be, that the object that reacts to the notification, in the okButtonClicked: function, does not have a (valid) reference to your window. And then, the alert don't know on what window to display.

If you can send a reference to your window in the notification object, then you should be able to get the alert shown on the window you want.

example code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PanelButtonClickedNotification" object:[self window]];
```

And:

```
- (void) okButtonClicked:(NSNotification*)notification
{   
   NSBeginAlertSheet(@"Alert", @"Ok", nil, nil, [notification object], self,nil, nil,nil,@"Alert is being shown on window.");
}
```

this works in my test-project.

Comment: I am sending some `userInfo` while posting the notification.    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[sender tag]],@"value",nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PanelButtonClickedNotification" object:self userInfo:dict]; So I will not be able to send `window` as a notification object.

Comment: You could add it to the dict, that you are creating and parsing along. Of course only if it exists / the class knows the window.  

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[sender tag]],@"value",[self window], @"window", nil];   

And then retrieving it   

    [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"window"]

Comment: Can not pass `[self window]` while posting the notification because its in separate window controller ( in this only a panel window exists on which there are buttons and on press of those button, the notification is sent). The main window is in another window controller, in which I am receiving the notification... Also once the panel opens on the main window and notification is sent/received..after that, i cannot open a NSBeginAlertSheet in any other method.:(